# Unauthorized: {"error":"unauthorized","reason":"You are not a db or server admin."}

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following this [tutorial](http://wg-perception.github.io/capture/#upload) .When i try to upload a bag file using:

```
 rosrun object_recognition_capture upload -a 'asaad' -e 'myemai@email.com' -i silk.bag -n 'silk' -d 'Silk brand soy milk.' --commit milk, soy, kitchen, tod
```

i get the following error:

```
Unauthorized: {"error":"unauthorized","reason":"You are not a db or server admin."}
```

I'm not very familiar with couchDB so please bear with this question( which i know is of a very basic nature).
The same happens when i try:

```
rosrun object_recognition_core push.sh
```

or any other such command related to COuchDB, for that matter.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 & ROS Hydro.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220501/unauthorized:-%7B%22error%22:%22unauthorized%22,%22reason%22:%22you-are-not-a-db-or-server-admin.%22%7D/) by [Asaad Irfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23193/asaad-irfan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2015-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

what I believe is, you need a db account/profile associated with email you are using , It can be on your local system though pretty much the way GIT works on local systems and one makes commits and puch changes to that.

---

Originally posted by [Nouman Tahir](https://answers.ros.org/users/20072/nouman-tahir/) with karma: 35 on 2015-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asaad Irfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23193/asaad-irfan/) on 2015-11-08**:
i have an account on the couchDB and am logged into it. i also started couchDB before trying to upload the content on couchDB but that didnt solve the problem.